# Radio button value not rendering correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, json, radio-button

I have an issue with the radio buttons. I am fetching all the values say label, component etc from JSON and rendering it on view.

Example: I got two values for component radio button from JSON and I am rendering it on view but the issue is when I select the first radio button, the other radio values get unselected. **Note: Both of these are in different div.**

```
  {
    "autoselect": [
      "nihil est velit"
    ], 
    "component": "radio", 
    "description": "distinctio accusamus cum quod veniam voluptatibus dolor", 
    "editable": false, 
    "label": "qui excepturi laborum", 
    "options": [
      "nihil est velit", 
      "ad aliquid id", 
      "irure", 
      "veniam voluptas", 
      "velit ea consectetur"
    ], 
    "required": true
  }, 
  {
    "autoselect": [
      "qui soluta"
    ], 
    "component": "radio", 
    "description": "est rerum dolor quisquam", 
    "editable": false, 
    "label": "deserunt quia", 
    "options": [
      "qui soluta", 
      "aperiam ut", 
      "et nostrud"
    ], 
    "required": true
  }, 
  {
    "autoselect": [
      "occaecati impedit proident"
    ], 
    "component": "radio", 
    "description": "id cumque totam sapiente reprehenderit", 
    "editable": false, 
    "label": "sit ut", 
    "options": [
      "corrupti", 
      "quidem", 
      "occaecati impedit proident"
    ], 
    "required": true
  }
```

HTML Code

```html
<form name="myForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-horizontal" ng-hide="formMain">
      <div class="mainBody" ng-repeat="tag in renderTags.form_fields track by $index">
        <ng-form name="tag.form_name" id="tag.form_id">
          <div ng-switch on="tag.component" class="row">
            <div ng-switch-when="radio" class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-xs-3"><b>{{tag.label}}:</b></label>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="form-control" ng-repeat="option in tag.options" ng-disabled="!tag.editable" ng-required="tag.required" style="margin-right:10px !important;">
                  <span ng-if="tag.autoselect!==null">
                                            <span ng-if="tag.autoselect[0] === option">
                                                <input type="radio" checked ng-value="option" name="$index" ng-click="clicked(option,tag)">{{option}}
                                            </span>
                  <span ng-if="tag.autoselect[0] !== option">
                                                <input name="$index" type="radio" ng-value="option">{{option}}
                                            </span>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div ng-switch-default>

            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-form>
      </div>
    </form>
```

JS code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getForm = function() {
    var formdata = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'data.json'
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.renderTags = response.data.data;
      }, function(reason) {
      });
  };

  $scope.clicked = function(option, tag) {
    var index = tag.autoselect.indexOf(option);
    if (index > -1) {
      tag.autoselect.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      tag.autoselect.push(option);

    }
  }
});
```

Could you please help me on this?
[Link to Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tNIPAdwAXf7f4qe2XFjk?p=preview)

Try selecting one of the check box, other one's value goes off. **Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` attribute is used to group radio buttons. Set `name` attribute to `{{tag.label}}` so that all the radio buttons under one label will be grouped

Also use `ng-checked` with an expression `ng-checked="tag.autoselect[0] === option"` to check the default value

Change your `HTML <span>`

From

```
<span ng-if="tag.autoselect!==null">
  <span ng-if="tag.autoselect[0] === option">
      <input type="radio" checked ng-value="option" name="$index" ng-click="clicked(option,tag)">{{option}}
   </span>
   <span ng-if="tag.autoselect[0] !== option">
      <input name="$index" type="radio" ng-value="option">{{option}}
   </span>
</span>
```

To

```
<span ng-if="tag.autoselect!==null">
  <span>
    <input type="radio" ng-checked="tag.autoselect[0] === option" name="{{tag.label}}" ng-click="clicked(option,tag)" />{{option}}
  </span>
</span>
```

Here is the **[UPDATED PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/UjNo9qO2Eq63t8neNOHv?p=preview)**